# mule endpoint builder from java code

Tags: mule

The below code fetches the global endpoint named SomeInbound and is stored in an invocation variable named someUrl

`<set-variable variableName="someUrl"  value="#[app.registry['SomeInbound'].getEndpointBuilder().getEndpoint().getUri()]"/>`

How can we do the same thing in java(how to get that app object in java and also the other methods following that)

Answer (score 0):

'app' is just a MEL specific context object for accessing parts of the MuleContext etc. In Java you can grab the registry from the MuleContext like so: muleContext.getRegistry() and then use one of the lookup methods to get the object you want.

TO get the muleCOntext, there any many possible ways. Some of which are:

- From a test case.
- Injection or the @Lookup
  annotation:http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Lookup+Annotation
  Implementing MuleContextAware:
  https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/context/MuleContextAware.html
- Or if you're using a Callable component etc. you can get it from the 
  MuleEventContext : https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleEventContext.html#getMuleContext()